# C++ Ask user if input is correct error

Tags: c++

Im trying to add code so if the user mistypes they can go back in the program and retype the input but im not sure if the code i found and used is correct. here it is in my function:

```
/********************************************/
// Name: inspools                            /
// Description: Ask for and get number of    /
// spools                                    /
// Parameters: N/A                           /
// Reture Value: spoolnum                    /
/********************************************/
int spoolnum()
{
  int spoolnum;
  char type;

  cout << "Number of spools to be shipped: " << endl;
  cin >> spoolnum;
  cout << spoolnum << " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" << endl;
  cout << "Is this correct? [y/n] ";
  cin >> type;
  if ('n') << spoolnum;

  if ('y') break;

  return spoolnum ;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use a loop.

Comment: i tried looking online for an example of a loop and thats as close as i got

Comment: what's `if ('n') << spoolnum;` supposed to do?

Comment: Another hint: DO keep at it WHILE your program isn't correct.

Comment: @ Bala R my reasoning was that if n is inputed which means no it would restart the function but thats not valid

Comment: WHILE he's at it he should check google, it shouldn't take him no more than a short WHILE to find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the obvious hints at while loop but i am still struggling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you searched for loops, but I don't buy it. I imagine you are pretty new at programming. I'm going to give you the answer but not without some explanation first.

**How While Loops Work**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop):

[image]

> In most computer programming languages, a while loop is a control flow
>   statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a given
>   boolean condition. The while loop can be thought of as a repeating if
>   statement.

**Your Problem**

Your problem is that you want to keep making the user enter a choice until they enter `y`. To do this, you need at least a `WHILE` loop, or as other commenters have said a `DO/WHILE` loop.

I have never preferred `DO/WHILE` loops but others do prefer it.

The problems you may have with the below code is that you have more than just `y` returned in `cin` such as a newline (`\n`) character. You will have to handle that condition.

```
int spoolnum()
{
  int spoolnum = 0;
  char type = 'n';

  while (type != 'y') {
      cout << "Number of spools to be shipped: " << endl;
      cin >> spoolnum;
      cout << spoolnum << " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" << endl;
      cout << "Is this correct? [y/n] ";
      cin >> type;
  }
  return spoolnum;
}
```

or the alternative `DO/WHILE`:

```
int spoolnum()
{
  int spoolnum = 0;
  char type = 'n';

  do {
      cout << "Number of spools to be shipped: " << endl;
      cin >> spoolnum;
      cout << spoolnum << " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" << endl;
      cout << "Is this correct? [y/n] ";
      cin >> type;
  } while (type != 'y');

  return spoolnum;
}
```

In the above code, I removed your `if ('n') << spoolnum;` because frankly it does not make **sense**.

I also removed `if ('y') break;` because the `while(...)` loop will break once the condition is met, which is `type equal to 'y'`.

Comment: You should guide the OP in the right direction... but let them do their own homework assignments.

Comment: One day we are going to have to work with this person. I don't want to be explaining do loops to co-workers.

Comment: I think this is a perfect scenario for do/while. It prevents you from having to pre-initialize "type" in this example and saves you a line of code.

Comment: so this is all i need? how does it know to go back if anything besides y is entered?